# Cannot get pandas to import properly

Tags: python, pandas

I have spent the last hour trying to fix the pandas import error, but with no success.

Python version: 3.8.3
Pandas version: 1.0.4

I use Visual Studio code. Importing other modules works (tried with numpy). Pandas is installed using pip.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/38599/Desktop/course1/moduli.py", line 34, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    import pandas.testing
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas._testing import (
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\_testing.py", line 404, in <module>
    RANDS_CHARS = np.array(list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits), dtype=(np.str_, 1))
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

I've tried downgrading pandas and reinstalling it, but nothing fixed the error for me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

remove the line with string.ascii_letters from the code.. as the error says

Comment: My script (moduli.py) only includes one line of code, and that is the pandas import. The error is caused by just importing pandas. I don't believe I should be editing the pandas source script.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. I did the following and it worked.
select the py file you want to execute, for vs code menu select Run=>Start Debugging, it works perfectly. I think it is a bug in the current vs code

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file named `string.py` somewhere in your workspace, by chance?

If yes, that would be the problem. By Python rules, such a file is also a module named string, so whenever anything is trying to import string, your file gets loaded instead of the standard library module with the same name.